# 3 Class Classification based on a Bernoulli feature and gaussian feature

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

Consider a 3-class classification problem with mixed features, where one feature is Gaussian and another is discrete Bernoulli:

Prior class probabilities: $P(C_1) = .5$,      $P(C_2) = P(C_3) = 0.25$

$P(X_1|Y) \sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$ for all classes

$X_2 \sim N(Z_j, V_j)$, where $Z = [-1,0,1]$ for classes 1,2,3 respectively, and $V = 1$ for all classes. Eg $X_2$ for class 2 is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance 1.

The problem is to compute the following:

1. $P(Y|X_1,X_2)$
2. $P(Y|X_1)$
3. $P(Y|X_2)$